# Creating asterisks with for loop using arrays

Tags: java, arrays, loops, nested

I am trying to add asterisks on a line equal to the Int array. This starts at index 0 until the last index of the array. Here is what I have tried to do so far.

```
int e = 0;
int z = 0;
int[] yValuesInt = new int[yValues.length];

for (z=0; z<yValues.length; z++) {
    yValuesInt[z] = (int) yValues[z]; // converted array from double to int
}

System.out.println("" + yValuesInt.length);

for (e = 0; e<yValuesInt.length; e++) { // outside loop to continue until last index
    for (int j = 0; j<yValuesInt[z]; j++) { //inside loop to print asterisks
        System.out.println(":" + asterisk);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not to put you down but what kind of asterisk are you intending to add? The word or the ******?

Comment: @Eenvincible Say the Int value at index[0] is 4. I need to print **** on one line. Say the int value at index[1] is 6. I'd have to print six asterisks on the next line. Hope this helps.

Comment: I totally get what you want to achieve here; what you should do is loop through each and then figure out a way to know the index value (x) like if it is 4, the print it 4 times using another loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick glance at your code at the printing of asterisks there. I didn't check on the loop though.

```
for (e = 0; e<yValuesInt.length; e++) { // outside loop to continue until last index
    System.out.println(":");    
    for (int j = 0; j<yValuesInt[z]; j++) { //inside loop to print asterisks
        System.out.print("*");
    }
}
```

I believe this is what you're looking for as long as your loop count is correct.